# Finding time for the associate editor job – should one ask institute's management?

Tags: peer-review, journals, early-career, time-management, working-time

An early career researcher (ECR) is asked to become an associate editor for a reputable classical journal. Of course, no renumeration is offered. Based on the experience of other ECRs in a similar situation, I estimate that the job takes on average one full working day per month, or about 5% of working time. Let's not discuss working doing this job in the evenings or weekends (as, most surely often happens in reality). Let's say the ECR will take time from the regular working hours to do the editorial tasks. Now, the question: does the ECR have to discuss the decision of taking the associate editorship with the institute's management? On the one hand, becoming an associate editor is considered cool for the ECR's CV. So, it's not directly evident why the institute should pay for the working hours. On the other hand, helping to carry on with the semi-broken peer-review system is considered a common duty for all the academics, including the academic institutions.

Comment: This will largely depend on the institute's regulations and the contract that you have.

Comment: You probably mean "remuneration"?

Comment: An associate editor's workload can vary greatly between different journals. You should talk to other associate editors of the same journal to get a clear idea of what you're getting into. My impression is that most universities will be happy to have you take the associate editor job, as long as it doesn't prevent you from doing your job for the university. Such service to the profession would normally count in your favor in evaluation, e.g., for tenure.